# Entity Data Model unable to follow configSource attribute in web.config

Tags: .net, entity-framework, web-config

Within `web.config`, we are using the `configSource` attribute of the `connectionStrings` element to store connection strings in a separate file, for example:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="web.connectionStrings.config" />
```

In `web.connectionStrings.config` we then have:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseConnectionString" connectionString=" ... " />
</connectionStrings>
```

I've just added an Entity Data Model to the application. Unfortunately, it insists on adding its own connection string in to web.config, leaving it as:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="web.connectionStrings.config">
    <add name="EFConnectionString" connectionString=" ... " />
</connectionStrings>
```

which throws the following error when run:

> A section using 'configSource' may contain no other attributes or elements.

Moving `EFConnectionString` into `web.connectionStrings.config` solves this immediate issue (and, the database queries run with no issue), but the Entity Data Model cannot find it when I need to refresh it or add additional data.

Is there any way to tell the Entity Data Model to either follow the `configSource` attribute, or to use `web.connectionStrings.config` to store its connection string in?

Comment: Did you find a answer for this? Even I'm facing similar issue.

Comment: @KushalR I never did, unfortunately. We stopped development on that particular project several years ago now, so the need to solve it never came back up again.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the constructor of myDbContext from this

```
public class myDbContext : DbContext
{
     public myDbContext():base("name=myDb")
    {
    }
```

to this

```
public class myDbContext : DbContext
{
     public myDbContext():base("myDb")
    {
    }
```

and the problem was fixed.

I've no idea what myDbContext constructor has to do with configsource. But this change solved my issue.